# Proof verification: $x_n = \sqrt{n^2 +1} - n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

> Prove by definition: $x_n = \sqrt{n^2 +1} - n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

---

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$, then let $N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. Then $\forall n \geq N$ we have:

$$
|\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n| = \left|(\sqrt{n^2 + 1} - n)\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + n}\right| < \frac{1}{n} \leq \epsilon
$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes. Well done.

Comment: Ah thank you! Thankfully, it seems, that after some time the things in the beginning get easier!

Answer (score 1):

You could also prove this by applying..
Lt n>infinity Tn+1/Tn =0